# How to get route between two points on OpenStreetMap?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, maps, openstreetmap

I'm working on a web/app to find the optimal route for n points on a city, so i can travel through each one in the shortest amount of time possible. I wanted to use Google Maps API but it's not free, so i went for OpenStreetMap, so far i managed to show the map on the page:

```js
function initMap() {
   map = new OpenLayers.Map("map");
   var mapnik         = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM();
   var fromProjection = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326");   // Transform from WGS 1984
   var toProjection   = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"); // to Spherical Mercator Projection
   var position       = new OpenLayers.LonLat(long, lat).transform( fromProjection, toProjection);
   var zoom           = 14; 

   map.addLayer(mapnik);
   map.setCenter(position, zoom );
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    initMap();
});
```

I thought of picking a starting point, then find all the distances to the other points, pick the shortest, and from that point repeat the proccess and make a list, then make a route with all the points and display it on the map, or at least have and sorted list of the points.

Now i don't know how to get the route or distance from A to B, make the route with the points. And the OSM wiki it's kinda unclear. I don't know if i explained myselk well.

I tried google maps api, but it's paid. openstreetmap documentation is very unclear, i can't find examples anywhere, and i have no experience with geocoding.

Answer (score 2):

What you're trying to solve is commonly known as the [travelling salesman problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem) e.g. what's the shortest route for a given set of points. It is *"one of the most intensively studied problems in optimization"*.

The approach you are taking most closely resembles the
[nearest_neighbour_algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbour_algorithm), one of the first ever used to solve the problem and also quite simple: choose a point, find the nearest point to that one, and repeat until you're done.

In terms of implementation, I believe [this StackExchange answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/167019) has what you're looking for. It features a JSFiddle which accomplishes what you're trying to do and also uses OpenLayers like your code.

> ```
> var points = [],
> msg_el = document.getElementById('msg'),
> url_osrm_nearest = '//router.project-osrm.org/nearest/v1/driving/',
> url_osrm_route = '//router.project-osrm.org/route/v1/driving/',
> icon_url = '//cdn.rawgit.com/openlayers/ol3/master/examples/data/icon.png',
> vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector(),
> vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
>   source: vectorSource
> }),
> styles = {
>   route: new ol.style.Style({
>     stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
>       width: 6, color: [40, 40, 40, 0.8]
>     })
>   }),
>   icon: new ol.style.Style({
>     image: new ol.style.Icon({
>       anchor: [0.5, 1],
>       src: icon_url
>     })
>   })
> };
>
>
> console.clear();
>
> var map = new ol.Map({
>   target: 'map',
>   layers: [
>     new ol.layer.Tile({
>       source: new ol.source.OSM()
>     }),
>     vectorLayer
>   ],
>   view: new ol.View({
>     center: [-5685003, -3504484],
>     zoom: 11
>   })
> });
>
> map.on('click', function(evt){
>   utils.getNearest(evt.coordinate).then(function(coord_street){
>     var last_point = points[points.length - 1];
>     var points_length = points.push(coord_street);
>
>     utils.createFeature(coord_street);
>
>     if (points_length < 2) {
>       msg_el.innerHTML = 'Click to add another point';
>       return;
>     }
>
>     //get the route
>     var point1 = last_point.join();
>     var point2 = coord_street.join();
>     
>     fetch(url_osrm_route + point1 + ';' + point2).then(function(r) { 
>       return r.json();
>     }).then(function(json) {
>       if(json.code !== 'Ok') {
>         msg_el.innerHTML = 'No route found.';
>         return;
>       }
>       msg_el.innerHTML = 'Route added';
>       //points.length = 0;
>       utils.createRoute(json.routes[0].geometry);
>     });
>   });
> });
>
> var utils = {
>   getNearest: function(coord){
>     var coord4326 = utils.to4326(coord);    
>     return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
>       //make sure the coord is on street
>       fetch(url_osrm_nearest + coord4326.join()).then(function(response) { 
>         // Convert to JSON
>         return response.json();
>       }).then(function(json) {
>         if (json.code === 'Ok') resolve(json.waypoints[0].location);
>         else reject();
>       });
>     });
>   },
>   createFeature: function(coord) {
>     var feature = new ol.Feature({
>       type: 'place',
>       geometry: new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.fromLonLat(coord))
>     });
>     feature.setStyle(styles.icon);
>     vectorSource.addFeature(feature);
>   },
>   createRoute: function(polyline) {
>     // route is ol.geom.LineString
>     var route = new ol.format.Polyline({
>       factor: 1e5
>     }).readGeometry(polyline, {
>       dataProjection: 'EPSG:4326',
>       featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857'
>     });
>     var feature = new ol.Feature({
>       type: 'route',
>       geometry: route
>     });
>     feature.setStyle(styles.route);
>     vectorSource.addFeature(feature);
>   },
>   to4326: function(coord) {
>     return ol.proj.transform([
>       parseFloat(coord[0]), parseFloat(coord[1])
>     ], 'EPSG:3857', 'EPSG:4326');
>   }
> };
> ```

The above solution uses [OSRM](https://project-osrm.org/) which is a [routing](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing) engine, these are often used to determine what path to take to travel between places. I think using one of these would would be useful to you.